# Returning a wildcard (duplicate line) with Regex

Tags: regex, grep

I'm using WinGrep and Notepad++ (Windows) with some other software that uses Regex.
I would like to know if it's possible (and how) to duplicate a line with wildcard, essentially "returning a wildcard".

So the example would be a line such as:-

**VALUE01="bananamilkshake"**

and make it:-

**VALUE01="bananamilkshake"**

**VALUE01="bananamilkshake"**

...where "bananamilkshake" is the wildcard and could be any string containing letters and numbers.

My aim is to duplicate the line, then I could change the VALUE01 on the next line by using the end of the previous line, if that makes sense, so there's no need to increment the values because I can just do that by repeating the steps as a workaround.

I hope that makes sense, what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Stackoverflow's success relative to forums and mailing lists is due in large part to its format.  As part of that format, you click on the checkmark for the answer that works best for you.  This is what we do instead of marking the title with "solved".  For more information on Stackoverflow's
    peculiar customs, see: [What should I do when someone answers my
    question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you're looking for something like this:

```
(^VALUE01="[A-Za-z0-9]+"$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SAR0Ol/3).

In Notepad++, you can use the following in the "Replace with" field:

```
\1\r\n\1
```

Which will result in duplicating the line that matches the regex pattern above.

Comment: The key being `()` (not in your link) which captures the contents that can include wildcards.

Comment: @zzxyz The link is just a demo to show the matches. When using NP++, the pattern needs to be enclosed in a capturing group so it can be replaced. But you're right though, it might cause confusion, I just updated the link.

Comment: @LDAsh If Admed's answer solves your problem, [you should mark his answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left
of his answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/160242).  On Stackoverflow, this is how a question is marked as "solved."